# FusionCharts position of Text in a stackedbar2d

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts, stacked-chart

I have several stackedbar2d with very different values. In the bars have to be a text with also the value of the bar.

For the position of the text I have this line:

```
`"x": "$dataset.1.set.0.X - 90",`
```

in the script for the stackedbar2d.
The number of the x-position I have to change by every value of the bar length, otherwise the text is not on the same position in display.

Is there any solution for this problem? Maybe by an calculation with the whole length of both bars in pixel and a constant?

[Here is an fiddle example for that.](http://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/T5C6h/1786/)

first chart:

```
"groups": [
          {
            "id": "Callout", "items": [
              {
                "id": "CalloutLabel0",
                "type": "Text",
                "fontSize": "12",
                "bold": "0",
                "fillcolor": "#333",
                "text": "N=164 MW=5.8",
                "align":"left",
                "x": "$dataset.1.set.0.X - 200",
                "y": "$dataset.0.set.0.starty + 10"
              },

`$dataset.1.set.0.X - 200`
```

in the chart below:

```
$dataset.1.set.0.X - 320
```

if both charts have $dataset.1.set.0.X - 320 [then you have this result here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5C6h/2749/). (please use chrome browser for fiddle maybe)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be preety close with your implementation.You might wanna know more about macros from [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations#use-macros)
I am not completely sure about the exact visual you want to achieve finally, but this is my assumption - You want to place these annotated texts in somewhere inside the grey part.
Simple modifications shown in the snippet below:

- Use macro $centerX
- Subtracting 45 because the entire width of this text was close to 90. So subtracting (90 / 2 = 45) makes it center.
- I wasnt sure why the same set was used in all the entries. `$dataset.1.set.0`. As data is dynamic, please try using appropriate set index
- One more suggestion around duplicate id found inside the annotated groups. IDs, meant to be unique, right :)

```js
//BarCharts TOP 5
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
  type: "stackedbar2d",
  renderAt: "chart-container11a",
  width: "680",
  height: "230",
  dataFormat: "json",
  dataSource: {
    "chart": {
      "caption": "" + unescape("Top 5") + "",
      "subCaption": "",
      "xAxisname": "",
      "yAxisName": "",
      "yAxisMinValue": "5",
      "yAxisMaxValue": "7",
      "showXAxisLine": "1",
      "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
      "divlineColor": "#999999",
      "divLineIsDashed": "1",
      "numberPrefix": "",
      "paletteColors": "#D9D9D9,#02B051",
      "bgColor": "#ffffff",
      "borderAlpha": "0",
      "showCanvasBorder": "0",
      "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
      "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
      "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
      "legendShadow": "0",
      "valueFontColor": "#333",
      "showAlternateVGridColor": "0",
      "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
      "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
      "showHoverEffect": "1",
      "maxBarHeight": "20",
      "numDivLines": "0",
      "showValues": "0",
      "canvasLeftMargin": "200",
      "captionAlignment": "left",
      "showYAxisValues": "0"
    },
    "categories": [{
      "category": [{
          "label": "Item 1"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 2"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 3"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 4"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 5"
        }
      ]
    }],
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "",
        "data": [{
            "value": "6.3",
            "tooltext": "Item 1 MW=6.683"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.3",
            "tooltext": "Item 2 MW=6.673"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.3",
            "tooltext": "Item 3 MW=6.613"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.3",
            "tooltext": "Item 4 MW=6.598"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.3",
            "tooltext": "Item 5 MW=6.554"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "seriesname": "",
        "data": [{
            "value": "0.383",
            "tooltext": "Item 1 Diff. zum MW=+0.383"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.373",
            "tooltext": "Item 2 Diff. zum MW=+0.373"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.313",
            "tooltext": "Item 3 Diff. zum MW=+0.313"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.298",
            "tooltext": "Item 4 Diff. zum MW=+0.298"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.254",
            "tooltext": "Item 5 Diff. zum MW=+0.254"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "trendlines": [{
      "line": [{
          "startvalue": "5.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "70",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": "5"
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "5.5",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "0",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "6.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "6.5",
          "color": "#333",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "7.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "70",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": "7"
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "5",
          "endValue": "6",
          "color": "#ff0000",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "6",
          "endValue": "6.5",
          "color": "#FFFF00",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "6.5",
          "endValue": "7",
          "color": "#02B052",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        }
      ]
    }],
    "annotations": {
      "drawImmediately": "1",
      "showbelow": "0",
      "groups": [{
        "id": "Callout",
        "items": [{
            "id": "CalloutLabel1",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=63 MW=6.7",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.0.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.0.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel2",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=159 MW=6.7",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.1.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.1.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel1",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=62 MW=6.6",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.2.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.2.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel1",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=127 MW=6.6",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.3.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.3.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel1",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=168 MW=6.6",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.4.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.4.starty + 10"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
}).render();

//BarCharts BOTTOM 5
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
  type: "stackedbar2d",
  renderAt: "chart-container11b",
  width: "680",
  height: "230",
  dataFormat: "json",
  dataSource: {
    "chart": {
      "caption": "" + unescape("Bottom 5") + "",
      "subCaption": "",
      "xAxisname": "",
      "yAxisName": "",
      "yAxisMinValue": "5",
      "yAxisMaxValue": "7",
      "showXAxisLine": "1",
      "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
      "divlineColor": "#999999",
      "divLineIsDashed": "1",
      "numberPrefix": "",
      "paletteColors": "#D9D9D9,#FF0000",
      "bgColor": "#ffffff",
      "borderAlpha": "0",
      "showCanvasBorder": "0",
      "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
      "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
      "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
      "legendShadow": "0",
      "valueFontColor": "#333",
      "showAlternateVGridColor": "0",
      "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
      "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
      "showHoverEffect": "1",
      "maxBarHeight": "20",
      "numDivLines": "0",
      "showValues": "0",
      "canvasLeftMargin": "201",
      "captionAlignment": "left",
      "showYAxisValues": "0"
    },
    "categories": [{
      "category": [{
          "label": "Item 6"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 7"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 8"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 9"
        },
        {
          "label": "Item 10"
        }
      ]
    }],
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "",
        "data": [{
            "value": "5.799",
            "tooltext": "Item 6 MW=5.799"
          },
          {
            "value": "5.966",
            "tooltext": "Item 7 MW=5.966"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.000",
            "tooltext": "Item 8 MW=6.000"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.034",
            "tooltext": "Item 9 MW=6.034"
          },
          {
            "value": "6.050",
            "tooltext": "Item 10 MW=6.050"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "seriesname": "",
        "data": [{
            "value": "0.501",
            "tooltext": "Item 6 Diff. zum MW=-0.501"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.334",
            "tooltext": "Item 7 Diff. zum MW=-0.334"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.300",
            "tooltext": "Item 8 Diff. zum MW=-0.300"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.266",
            "tooltext": "Item 9 Diff. zum MW=-0.266"
          },
          {
            "value": "0.250",
            "tooltext": "Item 10 Diff. zum MW=-0.250"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "trendlines": [{
      "line": [{
          "startvalue": "5.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "70",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": "5"
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "5.5",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "0",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "6.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "6.5",
          "color": "#333",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": ""
        },
        {
          "startvalue": "7.0",
          "color": "#333",
          "alpha": "70",
          "valueOnRight": "2",
          "displayvalue": "7"
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "5",
          "endValue": "6",
          "color": "#ff0000",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "6",
          "endValue": "6.5",
          "color": "#FFFF00",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        },
        {
          "isTrendZone": "2",
          "startvalue": "6.5",
          "endValue": "7",
          "color": "#02B052",
          "alpha": "7",
          "valueOnRight": "0",
          "displayvalue": " "
        }
      ]
    }],
    "annotations": {
      "drawImmediately": "1",
      "showbelow": "0",
      "groups": [{
        "id": "Callout",
        "items": [{
            "id": "CalloutLabel0",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=164 MW=5.8",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.0.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.0.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel1",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=117 MW=6.0",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.1.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.1.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel2",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=59 MW=6.0",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.2.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.2.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel3",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=59 MW=6.0",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.3.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.3.starty + 10"
          },
          {
            "id": "CalloutLabel4",
            "type": "Text",
            "fontSize": "12",
            "bold": "0",
            "fillcolor": "#333",
            "text": "N=121 MW=6.1",
            "align": "left",
            "x": "$dataset.0.set.4.centerX - 45",
            "y": "$dataset.0.set.4.starty + 10"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
}).render();
```

```html
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<!-- Multi-series line chart -->

<div id="chart-container11a">FusionCharts will render here</div>
<div id="chart-container11b">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of annotations in StackedBar chart is not utilizing the macros optimally, because you are placing the annotation texts on the first dataset(Grey - #D9D9D9), but you are setting the macro in "x" attribute with respect to the second dataset(Green or Red) as below :

```
"x": "$dataset.1.set.0.X - 320",
```

which is not a proper implementation.

You need to set the macros in the "x" attribute with respect to the dataset and set(plots) on which you are displaying the annotations. This will help you to align them all using the same padding with the macros for the respective annotations. Refer to the code below :

```
Plot 1 - "x": "$dataset.0.set.0.STARTX+30",

Plot 2 - "x": "$dataset.0.set.1.STARTX+30",

Plot 3 - "x": "$dataset.0.set.2.STARTX+30",

Plot 4 - "x": "$dataset.0.set.3.STARTX+30",

Plot 5 - "x": "$dataset.0.set.4.STARTX+30",
```

Refer the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zyk2n5f0/